# Best datastructure for iterating over and moving elements to front

Tags: c++, list, vector, data-structures

As part of a solution to a bigger problem that is finding the solution to a maximum flow problem. In my implementation of the relabel-to-front algorithm I'm having a performance bottleneck that I didn't expect.

The general structure for storing the graph data is as follows:

```cpp
struct edge{
    int destination;
    int capacity;
};

struct vertex{
    int e_flow;
    int h;
    vector<edge> edges;
};
```

The specifics of the algorithm are not that important to the question. In the main loop of the solution I'm looping over all vertices except the source and the sink. If at some point a change is made to a vertex then that vertex is put at the front of the list and the iteration starts again from the start. Until the end of the list is reached and we terminate. This part looks as follows now

```cpp
//nodes are 0..nodeCount-1 with source=0 and sink=nodeCount-1
vector<int> toDischarge(nodeCount-2,0);
for(int i=1;i<sink;i++){
    toDischarge[i-1]=i;
}//skip over source and sink
//custom pointer to the entry of toDischarge we are currently accessing
int point = 0;
while(point != nodeCount-2){
    int val = toDischarge[point];
    int oldHeight = graph[val].h;
    discharge(val, graph, graph[val].e_flow);
    if(graph[val].h != oldHeight){
        rotate(toDischarge.begin(), toDischarge.begin()+point, toDischarge.begin()+point+1);
        //if the value of the vertex has changed move it to the front and reset pointer
        point = 0;
    }
    point++;
}
```

I tried using an `std::list` data structure before the vector solution but that was even slower even though conceptually that didn't make sense to me since (re)moving elements in a list should be easy. After some research I found out that it was probably horribly performant due to caching issues with list.

Even with the vector solution though I did some basic benchmarking using valgrind and have the following results.

[image]

If I understand this correctly then over 30% of my execution time is just spent doing vector element accesses.

Another solution I've tried is making a copy of the vertex needed for that iteration into a variable since it is accessed multiple times, but that was even worse performance because I think it is also making a copy of the whole edge list.

What data structure would improve the general performance of these operations? I'm also interested in other data structures for storing the graph data if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this is what `std::deque<>` is for. Imagine it as a 'non-continuous vector', or some vector-like batches tied together. You can use the same interface as `vector`, except that you cannot assume that adding an index to the first element's pointer results in the given element (or anything sensible other than UB); you need to use `[]` for indexing. Also, you have `dq.insert(it, elem);` that's quick if `it` is `std::begin(it)` or `std::end(it)`.

Comment: This worked very well and reduced the impact of the operations on the total running time significantly.